# Passing parameter from lightning JS controller to apex class

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am unable to pass parameter from the lightning controller to the apex class. Whenever I use debug the passed value seems null.

**JavaScript Controller**

```
add : function(cmp,event,helper) {

    event.target.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("cartdiv").style.display = 'block';
    var selectedAccount =event.target.id; 
    var act = cmp.get("c.Cartveg");
    act.setParams({"s":selectedAccount});
    act.setParams({"cartlist" : cmp.get("v.cart")});
    act.setCallback(this,function(a){
        cmp.set("v.cartitem",a.getReturnValue());
    });       
    $A.enqueueAction(act);
    cmp.set("v.whichButton", selectedAccount);
}
```

**Apex Class**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Vegetable__c> Cartveg(string s,List<Vegetable__c> cartlist)
{       system.debug(s);
  List<Vegetable__c>  clist= [SELECT Id, Name , Price__c , img__c 
                                FROM Vegetable__c where Name =:s];

    clist.addAll(cartlist); 
    system.debug(clist);
    return clist;
}
```

Value of s is null. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lightning you need to set param

`setParams` accept the multiple values so you need to pass

```
setParams({"s":selectedAccount, "cartlist" : cmp.get("v.cart")});
```

you need to pass both `s` and `cartlist` in single params

### complete code

```
add : function(cmp,event,helper) {

    event.target.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("cartdiv").style.display = 'block';
    var selectedAccount =event.target.id; 
    var act = cmp.get("c.Cartveg");
    act.setParams({"s":selectedAccount, "cartlist" : cmp.get("v.cart")});
    act.setCallback(this,function(a){
        cmp.set("v.cartitem",a.getReturnValue());
    });       
    $A.enqueueAction(act);
    cmp.set("v.whichButton", selectedAccount);
}
```